# Graphs in Google Sheets: Negative minimum limit for vertical axis

Tags: google-sheets, graph

In Google Sheets, I've made a line chart.

Since there are some negative values, the graph needs to dip below zero.

[image]

However, the minimum value is about -480,000 and the automatic lower-end of the vertical axis is -2,500,000. No problem, I say: I'll just change the vertical axis minimum value to -500,000 and the problem will be fixed.

Turns out, the chart ignores any negative values bigger than -2,500,000 I provide for the vertical axis minimum value. If I provide zero or a positive value or a negative value smaller than -2,500,000 (e.g. -3,000,000), this is duly reflected in the chart. But like a teenager, it pretends not to listen to me when the minimum value is between -2,500,000 and 0.

Is this a (known) bug in Google Sheets, or am I missing something basic?

P.S. It seems to be a bug, because the minimum value starts working within that range if I also provide a maximum value.

Comment: Hey I believe its an incremental setting by Google Sheets. You might need to set both your max and min values to achieve the increments that match your desire output. In this case, your increments seems to be in 2,500,000. Try adjusting your max value as 9,000,000.

Comment: Can you provide an example data set?